# How to take a screenshot of terminal

Tags: linux, terminal, screenshot

I have to do a screenshot of a terminal, but to be clear I mean whole terminal commands typed from the start of its session (not only these lines visible on screen).

I've known the purpose of <kbd>Prt Sc</kbd> button on keyboard to take screenshot all of terminal's content and merge it in some graphical program like ex. Gimp but I'm looking for some instant "take photo" method.

Comment: This depends on your Desktop / Window Manager. You can try Control + PrintScreen or Alt + PrintScreen or Shift + PrintScreen or similar.

Comment: You can output the contents of `~/.bash_history` to a text file.  Its up to you if you want to clear the history after taking the snapshot, though.

Answer (score 3):

You don't want a photo, most likely.  What you're looking for is a cut-n-paste list of the session, right?  and it's much more helpful to have that in text form.  So there is actually a utility that does exactly that, giving a new shell to start with called a "typescript" that exists on most unix-like boxes.  It may be called "typescript" or "script".  Example usage:

Creates a file called 'typescript' with what I did inside of it; note
that the history number restarted at 1001 for me, which indicates it
actually started a new shell (bash in this case, but any shell would work):

```
13:00 wjh [1198]: script
Script started, file is typescript
13:00 wjh [1001]: echo "hello world"
hello world
13:01 wjh [1002]: echo "cool"
cool
13:01 wjh [1003]: exit
exit
Script done, file is typescript
```

Now we can see that the contents of the text file `typescript` is
pretty much exactly what was above:

```
13:01 wjh [1199]: cat typescript
Script started on Tue 07 Jan 2014 01:00:47 PM PST
13:00 wjh [1001]: echo "hello world"
hello world
13:01 wjh [1002]: echo "cool"
cool
13:01 wjh [1003]: exit
exit
```

Comment: Yes, I agree with you in almost all cases that you mention, but the point of this question is that I just simple need a picture (I know that is not pro-computer way) of these commands. I also know the simplest thing like cut-and-paste method, but the main reason I asked this question is that it looks much more better when is printed with colors and layout like the shell does. 
So I don't understand why this question is voting down.

Answer (score 1):

gnome-screenshot -a will give you the ability to take a screenshot of whatever area you choose, that could work for your use case

Answer (score 1):

From a script, In a **X** environment:

---

**Set dynamically the terminal title:**

From our script, a way to change the terminal title using ansi sequences:

```
echo -e "\033]0;Term | myApp\007";
```

**Capture a png by window title:**

Now we can search for the window id by the exact title using `wmctrl` and pass the id to the `import` utility:

```
import -window $(wmctrl -l | grep -i 'Term | myApp' | awk '{print $1}') ~/Pictures/capture.png
```

---

**Build a gif:**

Example to tweak, take 5 captures every second then convert them in order to a gif using `convert`, in an infinite 2 seconds loop.

```
rm -f /tmp/*png && for i in {1..5}; do import -window $(wmctrl -l | grep -i 'Term | myApp' | awk '{print $1}') /tmp/$i.png && sleep 1; done && convert -delay 200 -loop 0 /tmp/*.png animation.gif
```

**Build a video:**

Example to tweak, take 50 capture, every 30 ms, and convert to a mp4 video with ffmpeg. (Since ffmpeg doesn't support window capture by id)

```
rm -f /tmp/*png && for i in {1..50}; do import -window $(wmctrl -l | grep -i 'Term | myApp' | awk '{print $1}') /tmp/$i.png && sleep 0.03; done && ffmpeg -framerate 1 -pattern_type glob -i '/tmp/*.png' -c:v libx264 -r 30 OUT.mp4
```

Comment: I need 20 screenshots of a browser website (only text) to be taken every 30 seconds. Would gif or video be better? The pic-text then should be transfered via OCR (Tesseract) to a textfile probably with Google Cloud.

Comment: Seems like a complicated way to retrieve a website text content! Anyway use the frame pictures directly, in this example the png files are written to the temp `/tmp/` folder. Simply use those png, and maybe another path (not `/tmp/`).